# Determine azure function execution completion using REST api

Tags: azure, azure-functions

Is it possible to know whether the azure function is currently running, or has completed execution using REST Apis?

I dug up their official documentations, forums and even googled but finding nothing related.

Answer (score 2):

Not REST API, but you can see the logs of executions in Table Storage:

[image]

you can get Start and End time from there.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to visit portal explicitly but query it via rest API due to my own internal requirements.Is it possible to access table storage via rest API then?

Comment: I didn't mean you should do it in the portal. Table Storage has API to retrieve these entries

Comment: Oh ohkay, let me search for these apis then, thanks for the info

Answer (score 1):

You can do a GET on the Function or the App to retrieve the status. Good resource to explore different API calls and responses is [resources.azure.com](https://resources.azure.com)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/webapps/getfunction

Comment: Resource explorer doesn't seem to show individual functions to me. Which response field should show the execution status?

Comment: Ah execution status - assumed you meant status of the app itself (disabled, etc.). Currently no way to list execution log from API. Closest bet I can think of would be leverage App Insights and use that API to query for running apps.

Comment: Thanks, but the response from that api is not showing whether that function is running, or has completed running.