# monitor azure functions from rest api

Tags: rest, azure-functions, monitoring

I need to monitor and control the functions in an azure functions app, from outside of azure portal.

I'm looking for a way to extract a list of functions, their execution history, their schedule and status.

Is there a rest API that can give me that information? or can I get it inside an azure function?

Searching for this on google gives me nothing but instruction on how to build a function.

BR Kresten

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have 5 Functions in an Azure Function App where I can get the list of functions using this [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/web-apps/list-functions):

[image]

[image]

I have found the REST API for a function in the Function App that gives the last Http Call (like Get, Post, etc, made) with the given input and other information like Function Envelope given in this [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/web-apps/get-function) but not the current Status like Run History, Status, etc.

[image]

AFAIK, REST APIs are not available for Function App Logs to show the live history of the current execution history and execution status.

You can get the current and previous execution logs/history of the functions in any Azure Function App in [Live Metrics](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65820125) Portal Window and also using Log Analytics Workspace queries such as `requests`:

[image]

You can't get the current live execution status, history through API as complete details given in this SO [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59506028) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47036780) by the users @*cijothomas* and @*MikhailShilkov*.